# How to improve import speed on SQL Workbench/J

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

Tried like below, but it imports terribly slow, with speed 3 rows/sec

```
WbImport -file=c:/temp/_Cco_.txt
         -table=myschema.table1
         -filecolumns=warehouse_id,bin_id,cluster_name
         ---deleteTarget
         -batchSize=10000
         -commitBatch
```

Comment: Which DBMS product and JDBC driver are you using? Are you maybe sending that over a slow network connection? Do you have many indexes defined on the `confidential` table? What are the data types of those three columns?

Comment: Relational DB, jdbc:redshift, warehouse network with good bandwidth, "confidental" include only 2 indexes , 3 x varchar data type.

Answer (score 1):

WbInsert can use the [COPY API](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html) of the Postgres JDBC driver.

To [use it](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/command-import.html#import-pg-copy), use

```
WbImport -file=c:/temp/_Cco_.txt
         -usePgCopy
         -table=myschema.table1
         -filecolumns=warehouse_id,bin_id,cluster_name
```

The options `-batchSize` and `-commitBatch` are ignored in that case, so  you should remove them.

SQL Workbench/J will then essentially use the equivalent of a `COPY ... FROM STDIN`. That should be massively faster than regular INSERT statements.

This requires that the input file is formatted according to the requirements of the COPY command.

Answer (score 0):

`WbImport` uses `INSERT` to load data. This is the *worst* way to load data into Redshift.

You should be using the `COPY` command for this as noted in the Redshift documentation:

["We strongly recommend using the COPY command to load large amounts of data. Using individual INSERT statements to populate a table might be prohibitively slow."](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading_tables_with_the_COPY_command.html)

Comment: Hey, im not a owner of this redshift cluster , thats why i cant use Bulk Copy mode.
Looking for  a best  alternative. 
Maybe i will try with another ide, that doesn't need to use s3 permissions.